# How can I find out why the compiler is automatically creating copy constructors in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm updating a VS2010 C++ application to VS2012 and I'm getting the error

```
cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
```

This appears to be due to the complier generated function

`CObArray::CObArray(const CObArray &)`.

Is there a way I can disable the compile generated functions?  Or a way of knowing why it's creating the functions?

Comment: `This appears to be due to the complier generated function` Why do you think so?

Comment: Because the compiler output says "This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CObArray::CObArray(const CObArray &)'"

Comment: Don't try to copy your objects?

Comment: There is a Copy() function that is supposed to be used instead of the copy constructor which is private. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f24tx153.aspx

Comment: You have an error in the code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Do you already understand how compiler generated functions work in general and believe there's a specific reason why the copy constructor shouldn't be generated in this case?

Comment: This is very intentional for the CObject class, it has its copy constructor and assignment operator declared *private*.  In modern C++ they would have been declared `= delete`.  You must likewise ensure that your CObject-derived class cannot be copied.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, however they do not address my question: "Is there a way I can disable the compiler generated functions?"

Comment: Yes, I understand how compiler generated functions work, but they are causing the error.  It's a huge application and I know somewhere in the code there is an object being copied when it shouldn't be, I need to find out where this copy is occurring so I can fix this code.